# Group by middle node in gremlin

Tags: group-by, titan, gremlin

All

I am doing Rank of Neighbors problem using `gremlin`.
Here is the details of this problem:
Rank of neighbors (SQ : Ranking)
Given a start node v and two edge types Ei and Ej, return k neighbors of v with the
edge type Ei with the highest number of out-going edges of edge type Ej .
For instance, list k friends of a given person ranked by the number of sports each friend
plays.
Here is my code in gremlin:
`g.V().has('unique1',1220).out('relation1').as('a').out('relation2').as('b').select('a','b')`
I am trying to group the results by nodes marked by 'a', and then return some properties and the number of each group as the results.
For example:
If the graph has the relationships:

```
a->b->c<br>
a->b->d<br>
a->e->f<br>
a->e->g<br>
```

Ideally, the result I want should be:
b:2
e:2
How can I revise my query to get the correct result.
And if it is possible, how can I get the result in descending order of the number.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

g.V().has('unique1',1220).out('relation1').as('a').out('relation2').as('b').select('a').values('unique1').groupCount().order(local).by(valueDecr)

This is the answer I want, I have figured this out.